# How can I flex-wrap these items the way I want them?

Tags: html, css

I have 5 images:

```css
.ribbons{
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
}

.ribbons > img{
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<h1>RIBBONS</h1>
<div class="ribbonrack">
  <div class="ribbons">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x60?text=Ribbon 1">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x60?text=Ribbon 2">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x60?text=Ribbon 3">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x60?text=Ribbon 4">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x60?text=Ribbon 5">
  </div>
</div>
```

I want them to flex to end up arranged like below, but with what I've tried above can't seem to get it to work.

[image]

Any ideas? I would like this to work with both even and odd quantities of ribbon and without changing the order of the ribbons themselves in the DOM.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add `justify-content: center;` and change `flex-wrap` to `wrap` in your `.ribbons` class. Then populate your `<img>` in reverse order in the HTML.

```css
.ribbons{
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.ribbons > img{
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<h1>RIBBONS</h1>
<div class="ribbonrack">
  <div class="ribbons">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x60?text=Ribbon 5">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x60?text=Ribbon 4">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x60?text=Ribbon 3">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x60?text=Ribbon 2">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x60?text=Ribbon 1">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Population in the reverse order isn't really an option

Comment: I ended up fixing this by populating in the reverse order, so the credit goes to you.

Answer (score -1):

If your items are fairly static, you could consider using `css-grid` (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/), then you don't need to work with margins. However, for this to work I changed the ordering of `img` in the html template. There is also the `order` attribute which can change the order of items which are layed out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order.

```css
.ribbons {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
  width: 300px;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
}

.ribbons>img {
  grid-column-end: span 2;
}

.ribbons>img:last-child {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-column-end: span 2;
}
```

```html
<h1>RIBBONS</h1>
<div class="ribbonrack">
  <div class="ribbons">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x60?text=Ribbon 5">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x60?text=Ribbon 4">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x60?text=Ribbon 3">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x60?text=Ribbon 2">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x60?text=Ribbon 1">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Riudp.png)

**Here is you answer.....**

```css
.ribbons{
    display: flex;
    width: 300px;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  
  .ribbons > img{
    width: 150px;
  }
  .img5{
      margin-right: 80px;;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ribbon.css">
    <title>Document</title>

</head>
<body>

    <h1>RIBBONS</h1>
    <div class="ribbonrack">
      <div class="ribbons">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x60?text=Ribbon 1">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x60?text=Ribbon 2">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x60?text=Ribbon 3">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x60?text=Ribbon 4">
        <img class="img5" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x60?text=Ribbon 5">
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```